# Getting type of evdev device

Tags: linux, input

From the Linux userspace, how can I get the type (ie, mouse or keyboard) of an evdev/input_event device?

I know that I can enumerate them by reading `/proc/bus/input/handlers` or listing `/sys/class/input/` but it's unclear as to which devices are mice or keyboards.

lines in `/proc/bus/input/handlers` like `H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds` seem to suggest that this is a keyboard with the presence of 'kbd' but I can't find any actual documentation to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel doesn’t really reason in terms of device types, but more in terms of the types of events which devices can produce (see [the event codes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/event-codes.html) in the kernel).

As a result, you need some heuristics to identify device types. Many devices can produce key events; keyboards have the particularity of producing both key events (`EV_KEY`) and repeating events (`EV_REP`). Mice are, I think, the only devices which produce relative events (`EV_REL`).

Devices expose the event types the can generate in the `ev` file in their class `capabilities` directory. Each even type has a given bit offset, defined in `/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h`; `EV_KEY` is 1, `EV_REP` 20, `EV_REL` 2. You can look for those bits in the values given by `/sys/class/input/input*/capabilities/ev` to find the devices you’re interested in.

Answer (score 0):

To find details of any device (I use event22), you can run this (in terminal/python/C++):

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/input/event22
```

The output is a huge list of details, from which only 2 are important the product and vendor:

```
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0100"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b4"
```

When you use lsusb in a terminal, you also see these magical numbers. By removing/adding you can easily find out the numbers for your device e.g. a mouse, bluetooth device or barcode reader. For me I got following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 061: ID 04b4:0100 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Cino FuzzyScan F760-B
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I remove my barcode reader and run again, the Fuzzyscan device is gone. Then I know my barcode reader is 04b4:0100.

Now in the Evdev Library I can also find these number. First I make a program to run udevadm info for each and every device. At some point I find a device with 04b4 and 0100. The device name can be used for evdev. In C++ I can run:

```
int fd = open("/dev/input/event22", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)
int rc = libevdev_new_from_fd(fd, &m_evDev);
int vendor = libevdev_get_id_vendor(m_evDev),
int productId = libevdev_get_id_product(m_evDev);
if (vendor == 0x4b4 && productId == 0x100)
    printf("Wooow, you find the barcode scanner!");
```

Remark:
Maybe this device is not allowed for the user, then you need to add read/write rights like this:

```
sudo chmod a+=wr /dev/input/event22
```

I realize these are not very detailed, feel free to ask more.